# Vue Route 4 can’t read the link when refresh browser In Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

Vue Route can’t read the link when Refresh Browser in hexadecimal

The route is Arabic language in alias and route

Example You can visit sandbox:
[jmbz0.csb.app/تواصل](https://jmbz0.csb.app/%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84)

Dependecy

Vue 3

Vue Route 4.0.3

regard

Comment: please share the relevant parts of your code

Comment: Pls Check Link [The Code In Sand Box](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-feynman-jmbz0?file=/src/main.js)

Comment: I don't know much about RTL coding, but this seems to fix the problem `{ path: "/about", alias: ['/عنا', '/%D8%B9%D9%86%D8%A7'], `

Comment: Thax for quick solution but does not solve the problem specially if you have many links Note that in vue-route ver 3 it work normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick fix Use `encodeurl` As the answer form @posve vue-route team I open issues link  below

[The Answer for Encode problem](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3464#issuecomment-770382616)

[Document how to use correctly encoded paths](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3465)

Regards